# Laravel 5.1 custom method in controller

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

In a controller name tagController where I define a custom method

```
public function addTag($id)
{
    $book = $id; 
    return view('tag.create', compact('book'));
}
```

In the route I define the custom route method

```
Route::get('tag/addTag/{$id}', 'tagController@addTag');
Route::resource('tag', 'tagController');
```

From my view I'm calling the controller method

```
<a class="btn btn-primary various" href="{{url('/tag/addTag', $tag->id)}}">Add Tag</a>
```

I'm getting the error every time

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143:
```

This is routing problem but I don't understand to how to define a custom method in route and in resourceful controller. Please help to get rid of the error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the $ from the path

```
Route::get('tag/addTag/{id}', 'tagController@addTag');
```

Comment: @JasonMcCreary markdwhite's answer simply adds a name to a route. It doesn't fix the `NotFoundHttpException` problem.

Comment: + I see now. This answers stands alone :)

Comment: @BenSwinburne - indeed. My answer has been taken out and shot.